# Using static variables in C# Web Application - Accessing Session variables in class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, static

Forgive me for my lack of coding knowledge as well as ability to ask the right question.

I'm rather new to this ASP.Net Web Application thing (Core), yet I still wondered..

In my current application, I have a class that has a property in which it gets it from a static variable, set when a user requests a controller. So the flow is: User sends a request with a variable in body, if not specified in body, the StaticClass.StaticProperty (example) is then set to the variable the user specified in the body (or default = 0), data is returned based upon the variable. 
  Yet I wondered, since there is no thread guarantee on this variable, whether or not this could be changed or messed up when the web application gets 50,000 requests at once?

I looked into sessions and tried the following:

```
service.AddSession(); //Not sure this even does anything?
HttpContext.Session.SetString //Setting this works in the controller, but I cant access it elsewhere by GetString
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] // Cant even access System.Web.Httpcontext, doesn't seem to exist.
HttpContext.Current //doesn't exist either
Session["test"] //doesn't exist either
```

Can I send a session over somewhere? I'm pretty lost.

Not sure if any of this made sense, I'll try to elaborate if needed.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Updated info.

I have added this to my startup.cs:
services.AddSingleton();

```
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
```

and

```
        app.UseSession();
```

Setting the Session variable:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6arP.png

Using the Session variable:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1WAr.png

Variable is always null.

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Where did you try this stuff? Controller? Some other class?

Comment: I set the
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test",test);
in the controller, and I tried to access it in another class.

Comment: Did you do the setup to even have sessions in your startup? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#session-state

Comment: I did, I followed the exact same instructions.

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear what you are doing. So you are using Razor pages, and trying to access the session from there. Which should work. Can you try doing the Session Get in the controller, immediately after setting the value. Let's see if it doesn't even set the value, or it gets lost somewhere in the process.

Comment: Just tested, the GetString returns the right value. Well, I'm actually just trying to create a WebAPI in a better way than using a static variable in multiple requests, and this is the only way I didn't get hundreds of errors.

Comment: I've never used Razor Pages, so I might be wrong. But I believe the Razor Pages projects don't have controllers. I suspect the code in the screenshot is from different projects? One is MVC another one is Razor Pages project. Thus they have different sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpContext is accessible only from things that are request specific, since it's a context of one and only request. And new controller instances are created by the framework for each request, with injected HttpContext. It's the developers job to pass it further if the need arises.

I recommend reading this article about it: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/05/accessing-httpcontext-asp-net-core/

> First in your startup.cs, you need to register IHttpContextAccessor as a service like so :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

> When you create a helper/service class, you can then inject in the IHttpContextAccessor and use it. It would look like something not too dissimilar to this :

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

  public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
  {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
  }

  public bool IsUserLoggedIn()
  {
    var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    return context.User.Identities.Any(x => x.IsAuthenticated);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this might be what I'm looking for, but no matter where I access the context using this method, it is always set to "null".

Comment: Let me rephrase, all I really need to do is save a session variable for a user and then access it in another class.

Comment: This should work. Add code on how you are doing it. First the Startup.cs class, the Controller where you are setting something into a session. And a class where you are getting something from a session.

Comment: Is it not possible to create an instance of, WebUser e.g., that holds the context, and then  call the WebUser in another class to get the httpcontext? I'm just really trying to avoid static, and the previous answer you sent doesn't seem to fit in my code.